# After having upgraded to Angular16 Routes does not work anymore

Tags: angular, typescript

I've almost lost all last working day on this... is seems that whatever I put as route it's not managed and always a product page is loaded :

Here's some of my code:

main.ts

```
import "hammerjs";
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

app.module.ts

```
import {  NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NotificationModule } from "@progress/kendo-angular-notification";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TokenInterceptor } from "./auth/interceptors/token.interceptor";
import { BlobErrorHttpInterceptor } from "@ttgauth/interceptors/blob.error.interceptor";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ChartsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';
import 'hammerjs';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from "./auth/interceptors/error.interceptor";
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DialogsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { EditorModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-editor';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { ExcelExportModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { LabelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-label';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { PDFExportModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export';
import { PopupModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-popup';
import { SchedulerModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler';
import { ToolBarModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar';
import {CommonLayoutComponent} from "./common/common-layout.component";
import {AuthenticationLayoutComponent} from "./common/authentication-layout.component";
import {OnlineUsersComponent} from "./partials/users/online-users/online-users.component";
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { TemplateModule } from './template/template.module';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppRoutes } from "./app.routing";
import { TemplateService } from "./shared/services/template.service";
import { NgbActiveModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CommonLayoutComponent,
    AuthenticationLayoutComponent,
    OnlineUsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [

   // StoreModule.forRoot(REDUCER_TOKEN),
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: false }),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    DateInputsModule,
    DialogsModule,
    DropDownsModule,
    EditorModule,
    GridModule,
    InputsModule,
    ExcelExportModule,
    IntlModule,
    LabelModule,
    LayoutModule,
    PDFExportModule,
    PopupModule,
    SchedulerModule,
    ToolBarModule,
    PagesModule,
    TemplateModule,
    SharedModule,

    //Telerik
    NotificationModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TemplateService,
    NgbActiveModal,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BlobErrorHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

// Layouts
import { CommonLayoutComponent } from "./common/common-layout.component";
import { AuthenticationLayoutComponent } from "./common/authentication-layout.component";
import { BasicCanActiveService as BasicCanActivate } from "./auth/guard/basic-can-activate.service";
import { Page404Component } from "./extras/404/404.component";

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: CommonLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(x => x.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: "giftcards",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/giftcards/giftcards.module').then(x => x.GiftcardsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "calendar",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/calendar/calendar.module').then(x => x.CalendarModule)
      },
      {
        path: "headset",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/headset/headset.module').then(x => x.HeadsetModule)

      },
      {
        path: "guides",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/guides/guides.module').then(x => x.GuidesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "categories",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/categories/categories.module').then(x => x.CategoriesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "inventory-products",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/inventoryproducts/inventoryProducts.module').then(x => x.InventoryProductsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "countries",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/Countries/Countries.module').then(x => x.CountriesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "destinations",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/Destinations/Destinations.module').then(x => x.DestinationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "products",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/products/products.module').then(x => x.ProductsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "orders",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/sales/sales.module').then(x => x.SalesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "users",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/users/users/users.module').then(x => x.UsersModule)
      },
      {
        path: "companies",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/users/companies/companies.module').then(x => x.CompaniesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "discounts",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/marketing/discounts/discounts.module').then(x => x.DiscountsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "reviews",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/marketing/reviews/reviews.module').then(x => x.ReviewsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "operations",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/operations/operations.module').then(x => x.OperationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "reporting",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/reporting/reporting.module').then(x => x.ReportingModule)
      },
      {
        path: "configuration",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        children: []

      },
      {
        path: "guides",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/guides/guides.module').then(x => x.GuidesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "confirmations",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/confirmations/confirmations.module').then(x => x.ConfirmationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "carts",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/marketing/cart/carts.module').then(x => x.CartsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "suppliers",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/E-CommerceSubmitters/supplier/supplier.module').then(x => x.SupplierModule)
      },
      {
        path: "affiliates",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/E-CommerceSubmitters/Affiliates/Affiliates.module').then(x => x.AffiliatesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "Guide",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/E-CommerceSubmitters/Guide/Guides.module').then(x => x.GuidesSubmittersModule)
      },
      {
        path: "travel-agents",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/E-CommerceSubmitters/travel-agents/travelAgent.module').then(x => x.TravelAgentModule)
      },
      {
        path: "booking-questions",
        canActivate: [BasicCanActivate],
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/catalog/BokunAdditionalBookingQuestions/bokun-additional-booking-questions.module').then(x => x.BokunAdditionalBookingQuestionsModule)
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: AuthenticationLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(x => x.AuthModule)
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: "**",
    component: Page404Component,
  },
];
```

When I open http://localhost:4200/login , but also http://localhost:4200/something_not_existent it loads the /products page

I've created a project from scratch based on angular16 and I've copied all my applicaiton's files. I think the error is something really stupid but I'm no able to spot it alone

Thanks

Comment: <Can you share the source code? Also where have you written the <router-outlet> attribute?